# How to apply to multiple ML pipelines(Models) to the same spark stream

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-spark-ml

I have an use case where I have to apply multiple already trained models (e.g. M1, M2, ..Mn) on the same spark stream ( fetched from kafka).

The models were trained usining the isolation forest algorithm from here: 
https://github.com/titicaca/spark-iforest

I have found something similar with my case here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhRHQPCdldI, but unfortunately I don't know if the company Genesys (former AltoCloud) made this API  (StreamPipeline, Heterogenous Pipeline ) open source.

I handled this with the above schema code, but I don't know how optimal is.

```
//read the stream
val kafkaStreamDF = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", broker)
      .option("subscribe", "topic")
      .load
val myModels = Array("m1", "m2","m3","m4")
//parallize the input models in order to have multiple threads handling the same stream, otherwise blocked??
 myModels.par.foreach(lm => {

     //load the model     
     val model = PipelineModel.load(lm)

      kafkaStreamDF.writeStream.foreachBatch({ (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
        //apply model
        val pdf = model.transform(batchDF).selectExpr("CAST(to_json(struct(*)) AS STRING) AS value").write
          .format("json")
          .save("anom/" + lm +  System.currentTimeMillis())
      }).start().awaitTermination()
    })
```

Questions:
1. Therefore, I would like to know if there is any any Spark API for handling such an use case?

2. If yes, where can I find it?
3. If no, how can I optimally implement this?

Any idea, suggestions is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it can be done like [this](https://github.com/titicaca/spark-iforest/issues/18).... But what if if your processing time is more than receiving time. messages will be piled up which will cause slow down of streaming receive.  [iForest](https://github.com/titicaca/spark-iforest) uses tree structure for modeling data. it will take some time to complete algorithm.

I prefer to store in storage like hdfs partition wise... and apply ML on that in a batch way with fixed time intervals. so that you receive the messages with out any delay and process them effectively.